# Get the email address from the Billing Object in Magento (Checkout)

Tags: magento

I am trying to get the email address that the user enters on the onepage checkout - I have tried the following but I cannot see the email address anywhere within either object - any ideas?

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me unfortunately Amit, would you have any ideas why?
I am running this code directly within an observer that triggers after the billing section is submitted in the checkout

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
echo $quote->getCustomerEmail()
```